# CSS - How to display text below css style centered image?

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML code and I am trying to position the links right below the image, but fail badly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<style>
  html, body {
  height: 90%;
  background:#000000;
  color:#fff;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

  </style>
</head>


<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/3/1/7/1374685821502984977google%20logo-md.png">
<br><a href="/deutsch/">Deutsch</a> | <a href="/international/">English</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

However, I need to place the links right below the image (centered) but it seems like it's impossible.

I wonder if any of you knows a solution that would work in this case.

Comment: [`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) removes the image from the document flow. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <style>
       html, body {
  height: 90%;
  background:#000000;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}
 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
a{
  width: 100%;
}
      </style>
    </head>


    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/3/1/7/1374685821502984977google%20logo-md.png">
    <br><a href="/deutsch/">Deutsch</a> | <a href="/international/">English</a></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            html, body {
                  height: 90%;
                  background:#000000;
                  color:#fff;
            }
            img {
                max-width: 100%;
            }

            .container {
                position: relative;
            }
            .link {
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                left: 60px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/3/1/7/1374685821502984977google%20logo-md.png" alt="" />
            <h3 class="link"><a href="/deutsch/">Deutsch</a> | <a href="/international/">English</a></h3>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```